# Accidentally removed Mac OS X partition MacBook Pro (2014 Retina) with Boot Camp. How can I reinstall Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I wanted to install Windows 10 Pro via Bootcamp. While I was installing Windows, I accidentally deleted my Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) partition and installed Windows 10 over top of it.

How do reinstall OS X? I have 2 USB drives. I’m willing to reset to factory defaults and install Windows again.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hold Cmd/R at the chimes, which will boot to the Recovery partition if it exists, or Internet Recovery if not. Hope you have a backup. Golden rule - **never** let Windows touch the partitions on a Mac. It just doesn't understand how they are set up.

Comment: That's really useful. Since both partitions are formatted in FAT, I've reformatted  with Mac OS (Journalised) using disk utility in recovery mode and then started installation. It's downloading from internet and seems running ok. fingers crossed. This time, I've carefully chosen the correct partition. Hopefully, I'll have both OS running ok after it's installed.

Thanks for your quick response. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's perfectly installed. I've got both OS running and need to choose any OS at start up.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're willing to start fresh, then that's what I recommend.

At the boot menu (hold down Option at start-up), you can reinstall OS X from the *Recovery Partition*, through *Internet Recovery*, or through a USB installer (if you create one). If you have *Time Machine* backups, you can restore from them using the OS X installation process.

Once you've reinstalled OS X, you can use Boot Camp to handle installation of Windows 10 for you.

Comment: Perfect. I've done exactly as explained above. It's such a smooth installation. I'd love it.

Comment: Does that mean you're willing to accept that answer?

Comment: Yes. It's 100% correct.